# Sinch Charges for App to App call

Tags: android, android-studio, sinch, android-sinch-api

**Will SINCH charge for communication from both parties (Caller and Recipient)?**

As I can see that if i perform app to app call usin `SINCH` then my minutes are being deducted from caller and recipient both the parties.

I am aware that sinch allows for 2500 minutes free for app to app calling but does that mean like if I perform app to app call and total call duration is on 5 minutes than sinch will deduct 10 minutes (5 minutes from Caller and 5 minutes from recipient)?

Comment: May I know reason for down vote please ?

Comment: No, 5 minutes call will add 5 minutes to your total amount of minutes, when you reach 2500 in total we start to charge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, 5 minutes call will add 5 minutes to your total amount of minutes, when you reach 2500 in total we start to charge

Comment: Thanks. That will be helpful for deciding credits for my app user

Comment: Yes sir sure. here it is

Comment: Can you please look at this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326612/sinch-sesion-management-for-app-to-app-call

Comment: @cjensen 5 minutes will be added in both recipient's and caller's total minutes, or just caller's ? Also, 2500 minutes are per month for each user ?

Comment: @cjensen - Can you please look at this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434323/unable-to-get-dice-event-for-app-to-phone-call-in-sinch

Comment: @cjensen - Can you please look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176864/sinch-setsupportmanagedpushtrue-is-not-working