# SINCH :: Session Management for App to App Call

Tags: android, voip, sinch, android-sinch-api

I am developing an app with `SINCH` Platform for VOIP feature.

I am performing an **app to app call**.

I am aware that if Callback URL of application Server is set on `SINCH` Dashboard then it will not trigger `DICE (Disconnect Call Event callback)` [[refer here]](https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/#DiCE) event for App to App Call.

But I have to manage all call details with my App Server. How Can I manage it from my Mobile App? (Like how can i notify my app server that last call was about of 50 seconds? So my server can manage relevant credit for that user as per call time)

I know that I can perform request to my app server with call details after every call end but what to do in below scenario?

**1>** App to App call is on Going (Caller 'A' and Recipient 'B')

**2>** Caller 'A' presses home button while app to app call is onGoing.

**3>** Now Caller 'A' removes application from recent task as well (By Swiping Left or Right from Recent Task Screen)

**4>** Now Caller 'A' Clears app data and gets register again with My App.

In This case how can I send request from Caller 'A' Device to My App Server.

I have found that Sinch perform rest Request as "sandbox.sinch.com/V1/Session". Is It of Any Use for me?

Comment: I am not sur what your asking and what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @cjensen- By simple mean, What if my app gets crashed? How can i get call details of app to app call for the previous call that was ongoing before crash?

Comment: I would store the call id locallcy stored, what info are you after?

Comment: Are you chargning for app to app calls? You could post to your server the end time from user B when they hangup the call.

Comment: Yes I do charge for app to app call. so i need to send call details from both end (User A and B). Server will never come to know regarding crash in User A's app. So server will keep on waiting for User A's call detail while it will be submitted from User B.

Comment: @cjensen- Can you please look at my other question here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997169/sinch-phonenumberutils-issue-for-indonesia-number