# SINCH :: PhoneNumberUtils issue for Indonesia number

Tags: android, sinch, sinch-verification

I am using `PhoneNumberUtils` supplied by `SINCH`(sinch-android-verification-1.4.0) but is gives different outcome for Indonesia number.

It says that supplied number is not a possible number with below method in Android Verifiation SDK

```
PhoneNumberUtils.isPossibleNumber("895369074498", "ID")
```

But it says it is possible number in iOS Verification SDK.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the Android system version.
The reason is, we are using the native libphonenumber on the phone, it is updated whenever the system is updated on the phone.
For ios sdk it is different, it uses a libphonenumber lib from google, which is of a recent version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you please look into my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756340/what-is-the-session-period-for-sinch-pin-verification