# What is the Session period for SINCH Pin Verification?

Tags: android, voip, sinch, android-sinch-api, sinch-verification

We are developing an android and iOS app which requires number verification. I am doing it using `SINCH` Verification SDK. For my app, number verification is being done from Server side using `REST API` call using `SINCH REST API`.

We are not sure what is the default time period (Session Time Period) for `SINCH Pin verification`. And how can i change it if i wish to change it?

Can anyone help me finding out default `SINCH Pin Verificaiton` Seesion time?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its 3 miutes for sms

Comment: @cjensen - Thanks sir. Can I have a reference link which states the same thing? so I can use it for further reference. And can i change that default time period using some REST API?

Comment: @cjensen - Can you please look here for the question related to APNS certificate removal for iOS from SINCH Dashboard?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778933/how-to-remove-uploaded-apns-certificates-from-the-sinch-app-dashboard