# How to remove uploaded APNS Certificates from the Sinch App Dashboard?

Tags: ios, voip, sinch

We are developing calling app using **Sinch Sdk**. I want to remove the uploaded APNS certificate from App created in Sinch Dashboard.
I am not finding any way to remove existing uploaded certificate from it.

**NOTE ::-**
Now sinch have provided "Remove" options nearby uploaded certification for App.

Comment: there remove button is given in the box. simple