# Unable to get DICE event for App to Phone call in SINCH

Tags: android, voip, sinch, android-sinch-api

I am developing an android application where I have used `SINCH` SDK for `VOIP` service. 
It is working too good as per our requirement. I have only one issue that I am unable to get `DICE` event on Callback URL (which is set at `SINCH` dashboard) or `Call end` event in mobile SDK when I perform app to phone call and recipient declines the call.

I am able to get DICE event only if recipient pick ups the call and then disconnect it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Dice only occurs on PSTN calls not app to app calls

Comment: @cjensen- Here I am talking about App to Phone call only. I have no where mention regarding app to app call.

Comment: @cjensen - Can you please help me out with it? We are in mid of app development.