# SINCH setSupportManagedPush(true) is not working

Tags: android, voip, sinch

I have been using `SINCH` SDK's `VOICE` Calling feature for my project and it was working fine before until I update my google play service dependency.

I update it from '`com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1`' to '`com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.6`' and it has started giving me error. If I use the older version then it is working fine.

But I have to update it to make it compatible with latest firebase dependencies of version 10.2.6

Here is my crash report.

```
05-25 14:21:44.379 6239-6239/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.someapp.app, PID: 6239
                                             java.lang.LinkageError: com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.gcm.InstanceIDTokenService
                                                 at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
                                                 at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
                                                 at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
                                                 at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:338)
                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                 at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.gcm.TokenRefreshTask.start(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.DefaultSinchClient.setSupportManagedPush(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.someapp.app.sinch.SinchService.createClient(SinchService.java:109)
                                                 at com.someapp.app.sinch.SinchService.onStartCommand(SinchService.java:567)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3017)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Can Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version (3.11.1) of the Sinch SDK released in June with a fix on this problem. You can try and see if it works now.

Comment: Sure. I'll definitely try and will respond you soon

Comment: It is not working. Getting error as 'com.sinch.relinker.MissingLibraryException: lib/x86/libsinch-android-rtc.so'

Comment: Are you testing it on an intel atom based device? This mostly happens when you have another native lib (besides Sinch SDK) which is shipped with x86 arch. Note Sinch SDK doesn't contain a x86 version lib, but only x86_64. Unless you are really testing your app on a 32 bit x86 device, you could add x86 in your abi filter of gradle build file of your app. That usually solves the problem.

Comment: Here is how my abiFilter looks like : 
abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"